# NodeJS - Express can't read application/json data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, jsonparser

I'm trying to setup a NodeJS express JSON REST API for the first time, but I'm facing some troubles while trying to retrieve the JSON data coming from the requests (both GET and POST requests)

Here's the code:

```js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.get("/prova", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.headers["content-type"]);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
});
```

Here's the console.log();
When trying to make a request with Postman with some parameters:

```
application/json
{}
```

And here are the Postman request's details

[image]

Comment: It looks like your body is empty in Postman. Did you try putting some data there?

Comment: There should not be a body with a GET request so `req.body` should be empty.  Use a POST or PUT if you want to send data in the body with the request.

Comment: You are right guys, I was trying to insert parameters in the post request leaving the body empty, and even while trying the GET request I checked for the body (that was still empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid sending `body` with HTTP GET methods as per [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). As for the shown GET method this line `res.status(200).json(req.body);` is giving you an empty object, change it for example to `res.status(200).json({message:"Hello world!"});` to see the message. For the POST method you can access the `body` as you do with `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I inserted the JSON data in the body of the Postman POST request
For GET requests instead the data should be passed through the query string using res.param.xxxx (where xxxx is the param's key)